# Suppress Mouse event while watching DVD in full screen (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, mouse, fullscreen

Windows 7, PowerDVD

Whenever I watch a DVD in full screen mode, my wireless mouse sporadically seems to send some events (minor mouse movements) causing PowerDVD to display tabs / control bar. Is there a way to suppress this?

Solutions, either on PowerDVD or on Windows 7 side would be appreciated. So it is not specific to PowerDVD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two most likely problems, with simple solutions, are as follows:

1. The battery in the mouse is not fully charged (recharge it or replace it with a fully charged battery); when batteries get low in wireless devices like mice and keyboards, one of the common side-effects I've seen is unpredictable output (such as sporadic mouse movements or unexpected keystrokes)
2. The mouse (assumed to be the optical type) is on a surface that reflects the laser (place it on a cloth mouse pad or a dish cloth); reflective or shiny surfaces can result in sporadic mouse movements, or a reflection may even occur with less-reflective surfaces if there is a movement (e.g., the desk gets bumped accidentally) or some vibrations (e.g., from some mechanical equipment nearby), and a cloth mouse pad or dish rag will work very well to prevent this

I hope that one of these suggestions resolves your problem.

Comment: +1: Only thing I'd add.. consider disassembling and cleaning your mouse, or get a new one, as it'll probably only get worse. :)

Comment: Thanks for the support, I have crosschecked the above. It improves the situation, but it not completely goes away. It happens even if the mouse is switched of (it has an on/off switch). So only the wireless receiver is on. It is also not an "old" mouse, but relatively new also and well known product (so no low-cost / no name product). I need to further investigate...

Comment: @Horst Walter:  Make sure the drivers are up-to-date.  (@techie007's suggestion about cleaning is really excellent too.)

Comment: It is not completely gone, but much better now.

Comment: I'm glad there's some progress there for you.  By the way, does the problem clear up completely if you try using a different mouse?